# "CLS" Equivalent in BASH?

Tags: bash, terminal

How do you clear the entire terminal in BASH, like the command prompt's `cls` command?

`clear` doesn't work because it doesn't actually clear anything, it just scrolls down.

Comment: What do you mean "it just scrolls down"? You actually want to not be able to scroll up to see what was there before? What terminal are you using?

Comment: What about "reset"?

Comment: @Random832: I mean it just literally scrolls down, instead of clearing anything. (I'm using Ubuntu's default terminal, which I believe is gnome-terminal, sorry I forgot to mention that).
@Alex: I'd never heard of `reset` -- it seems to do exactly what I need, but is that *all* it does? Or does it reset other things too?

Comment: I guess my question is, why is "just scrolling down" a bad thing? The _screen_ is cleared. the stuff you scroll up for isn't part of the screen.

Comment: @Random832: Because it's annoying when I subsequently scroll up to go back to where it started, since it's harder to find the beginning.

Comment: `tput reset` does

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[You're probably looking for the **`reset`** command.](https://superuser.com/questions/122911/bash-reset-and-clear-commands)

However, the scroll-back buffer is not a feature of bash but of the terminal program. You didn't say what terminal program you were using.

Comment: +1 can't believe I didn't across that one in my searches, my question's definitely a dupe...

Comment: This has a huge delay unfortunately.

Answer (score 50):

Why don't you try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (control, lowercase "L"). This works in most shells (err terminals)...

In OSX terminal -

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> (command, l) leads to removing last typed command from display.

<kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> (command, k) leads to removing/clearing all display buffer.

`reset` (type this in terminal) leads to reset of terminal in case display becomes garbled.

not sure of equivalent in other unix flavors.

Comment: ctrl + L is the equivalent for clear. It scrolls down.

Answer (score 50):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this any better than what `clear` does with bash.

I think it's a feature that could be built into the terminal you're using though. I know the Mac Terminal app has a 'Clear Scrollback' menu option (command + k) that does what you're asking for.

Comment: +1 thanks for the info. I still need to get the difference between "shell" and "terminal" straight. :)

Comment: `shell` -> The software that is running. `terminal` -> A part of the computer, usually made out of glass, that you can throw.  `virtual terminal` -> A piece of software that is acting like a terminal. (xterm).

Answer (score 21):

**Short Answer**

```
clear && clear
```

or

```
tput reset
```

**Other Ways**

Here are all the ways you can clear the terminal screen in Unix:

```
clear               # only clear visible screen
clear && clear      # clear buffer as well
tput clear          # same as clear but by sending escape seq
reset               # clear + reset internal terminal state + 1sec delay
tput reset          # same as reset but without 1sec delay
stty sane           # don't clear screen but reset some terminal options
echo -e "\033c"     # same as tput reset but hardcoded escape seq
printf "\033c"      # same as tput reset but hardcoded escape seq
setterm -reset      # same as tput reset, setterm has friendlier commands
```

**Long Answer**

The `clear` command only clears the visible screen but not the buffer so you can do `Shift+PageUp` to scroll up in the terminal and still view previous outputs. If you want to get same result as `cls` then do clear twice like `clear && clear`.

Another related command is `reset` which (I believe) resets the internal state of the terminal program. Unfortunately, this command includes 1 second of delay to support really old terminals. So if you are not ok with that kind of delay then use `tput reset` which seems to do same thing as reset minus the delay.

But what does `tput` do? In Unix, you can send terminal all kinds of ASCII character sequences which are interpreted as commands by the terminal. This allows you to do funky things like blink or color the text or turn off echo (during password typing) or set terminal options or do clear or reset. This you can send by `tput clear` or `tput reset`. The `clear` and `reset` command are equivalent but they run from the binaries that comes with your distro and may do additional stuff. The `setterm -reset` is similar to `tput reset`. Setting terminal using `setterm` is usually better because unlike `tput` it has more readable options in general case however we here use tput because it's smaller in length :).

You might have also seen people using things like `echo -e "\033c"` or `printf "\033c"` which is equivalent to `tput reset` but the escape sequence is now hard coded. The `tput` looks up terminal properties and uses the right escape sequence.

Another related command is `stty sane` which actually doesn't do any screen clearing but it [sets many of the terminal options](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ustty.htm) to defaults so if your terminal looks garbled or if terminal stays blank when you type (for example, because you printed binary file to terminal with escape sequence to turn off echo) then this command might help. For extreme garbled terminal cases, you can use all of the available resetting techniques in the sequence. I've alias like this for such occasions:

```
alias cls='tput reset'
alias clshard='reset; stty sane; tput rs1; setterm -reset; tput reset'
```

**Related**

[What's the equivalent of the “cls” command from Windows/DOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25077/how-to-really-clear-the-terminal)

[What commands can I use to reset and clear my terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/122911/what-commands-can-i-use-to-reset-and-clear-my-terminal)

Comment: is there a command that achieves a similar effect of scrolling down into empty space until the current input is at the top of the window, but without deleting the history above it?

Comment: Unfortunately none of these are remotely as fast as Cmd-K (on Mac) which is instant. They all take at least around a third of a second. It doesn't seem to be possible to do it quickly.

Answer (score 17):

`xterm` will allow the escape sequence `ESC [3J` to clear the scroll back, so you could do:

```
alias cls="clear; printf '\033[3J'"
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the info, it's a different kind of answer and still useful.

Comment: the best answer so far nice job

Answer (score 9):

Use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. It removes the entries so I can't scroll up anymore.

So <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to clear everything including scrolling.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear terminal window but still be able to see everything when scrolling up.

Answer (score 1):

The [`clear`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/clear.1.html) command works for me.

But I personally find it impractical, because, for me, it clears the scrollback permanently and irreversibly. However, often I want just to insert some "marker"/"separator" into the scrollback, in order to be able to visually distinguish the "recent scrollback" from the "too old scrollback" (but sometimes ability to see the "too old scrollback" would be still useful). So I use something like:

```
yes '' | head -n100
```

That inserts 100 empty lines into the scrollback. (Inspired by [this answer](/a/35352568). You can vary the number of lines, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

In ~/.bashrc, the perfect cls is:

```
cls () {
    printf -- '%b' '\033c'
    return $?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Terminal you can map the "clearBuffer" action to the keyboard shortcut of your choice. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions, search for clearBuffer.

If you're on Windows and *not* using Windows Terminal, well, IMO you should be. To host bash inside Windows Terminal, add this to the "profiles" list in the Windows Terminal settings json:

```
    {
        "commandline": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "guid": "{cfef8f0b-5c87-412c-b9ec-0fe1c1befdcf}",
        "icon": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
        "name": "git bash",
        "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%\\documents"
    },
```